# WillPopScope not working for IOS in Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

in my flutter app I wanted to control will pop scope for IOS but it's not working. and I'm not using PageRoute as some examples suggested and [CupertinoWillPopScope](https://pub.dev/packages/cupertino_will_pop_scope) package is not working, it throws an error of `anchorpoint`. so can anyone help me out?

I tried `gestureDetector` for IOS but it's not triggering an action to previous page, which is what i wanted to do.

```
if (!Platform.isIOS) {
      return WillPopScope(
        onWillPop: () async {
          timerController.startTimer();
          !Navigator.of(context).userGestureInProgress;
          return true;
        },
        child: MyPage(),
      );
    } else {
      return GestureDetector(
        onHorizontalDragUpdate: (details) {
          int sensitivity = 8;
          if (details.delta.dx > sensitivity) {
            // Right Swipe
            //timerController.startTimer();
          } else if (details.delta.dx < -sensitivity) {
            //Left Swipe
            timerController.startTimer();
          }
        },
        child: MyPage(),
      );
    }
```

Comment: As per ur above code, you are only using willpopscope for any device other than android. Make sure to use willpopscope above a scaffold widget. Mainly WillPopScope is used to stop users from going back using device back button or swipe gesture.

Comment: @Md.KamrulAmin i'm using it on scaffold. so how can i detect IOS swipe back gesture?

Comment: Do you want the user to pop the current page and then run some functions?

Comment: @Md.KamrulAmin yes

Comment: https://medium.flutterdevs.com/tracking-screen-transition-by-route-observer-flutter-dadd8773699c
You can use RouteObserver as in the above article. Also, I will be posting an answer on how to run a function when navigator route is popped if that serves your purpose you can mark it as an answer.

Comment: @Md.KamrulAmin i really would appreciate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume you want to go from Page A(NewPage) to Page B(SecondRoute). To navigate to B from A, we use the following code:

```
Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const SecondRoute()))
```

And later, when the user comes back using swipe gesture or any other way to Page A and if you want to perform some action when user comes from B to A, we can call the 'then' in our Navigator.push function. Go through the below code to see text changes after user comes back to Page A from Page B.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class NewPage extends StatefulWidget {
  NewPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<NewPage> createState() => _NewPageState();
}

class _NewPageState extends State<NewPage> {
  String inputstring = 'Here is a default String';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Text(inputstring),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                          context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const SecondRoute()))
                      .then((value) => {
                            setState(() {
                              inputstring = 'New Text after navigation is popped';
                            })
                          });
                },
                child: Text('GO To Second Page'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SecondRoute extends StatelessWidget {
  const SecondRoute({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
    );
  }
}
```

Inside 'then' you can call any function you want to. Hopefully this serves what you are looking for.

Answer (score 5):

The issue is not solved let in GitHub : [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/14203)

I have made Custom class for `WillPopScope` it worked for me, I hope it will work for you as well.

```dart
class MyWillPopScope extends StatelessWidget {

  MyWillPopScope({required this.child, this.onWillPop = false, Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  final Widget child;
  final bool onWillPop;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Platform.isIOS ?
    GestureDetector(
      onPanUpdate: (details) {
        if (details.delta.dx > 0) {
          if(onWillPop){
            Navigator.of(context).pop();
          }
        }
      },
      child: WillPopScope(
        onWillPop: ()async{
          return false;
        },
        child: child,
      )
    )
    : WillPopScope(child: child, onWillPop: () async {
      return onWillPop;
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

More smooth and useful. You can take any action you want.

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'dart:io' show Platform;

class CustomWillPopScope extends StatelessWidget {

  const CustomWillPopScope({required this.child, this.onWillPop = false, Key? key, required this.action}) : super(key: key);

  final Widget child;
  final bool onWillPop;
  final VoidCallback action;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Platform.isIOS ?
    GestureDetector(
        onPanEnd: (details) {
          if (details.velocity.pixelsPerSecond.dx < 0 || details.velocity.pixelsPerSecond.dx > 0) {
            if(onWillPop){
              action();
            }
          }
        },
        child: WillPopScope(
          onWillPop: ()async{
            return false;
          },
          child: child,
        )
    )
        : WillPopScope(child: child, onWillPop: () async {
      action();
      return onWillPop;
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Put this as your top-level widget, possibly inside build function:

```
          return WillPopScope(
        onWillPop: () {
          if (Platform.isAndroid) {
            if (canNavigateBack) {
              //Navigate back actions
            } else {
              //Show exit dialog, etc.
            }
          }
          return Future.value(false);
        },
        child: Platform.isIOS
            ? GestureDetector(
                onHorizontalDragEnd: (details) {
                  if (details.velocity.pixelsPerSecond.dx > 50) {
                    if (canNavigateBack) {
                      //Navigate back actions
                    } else {
                      //Show exit dialog, etc.
                    }
                  }
                },
                child: _anotherWidget())
            : _anotherWidget(),
      );
```